# Twelfth rebus to exercise your brain on

Tags: rebus

I think it would be a blast to get paid for creating rebuses!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> I'm not made of money.

Comment: You got it!  Nice job!

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> I'm filthy rich.

Because

> There is a I, M, Not clean, and money.

Comment: That's an interesting take on it, Quantum.  But the third image goes with the first two.

Comment: Sorry, my previous version of that comment was a case of my usual addledness.